# Why can't a function go after Main

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Why can't I put a function after main, visual studio cannot build the program. Is this a C++ quirk or a Visual Studio quirk?

eg.

```
int main()
{
   myFunction()
}

myFunction(){}
```

will produce an error that main cannot use myFunction

Comment: `myFunction()` is a syntax error, whereas `myFunction();` isn't. You must first declare the function prototype before calling it.

Comment: Maybe because you're calling `myFunction` without an overhead prototype before you defined it.

Comment: You also forgot the semi-colon and the return type.
`myFunction();` and `void myFunction() {}`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can, but you have to declare it beforehand:

```
void myFunction(); // declaration

int main()
{
   myFunction();
}

void myFunction(){} // definition
```

Note that a function needs a return type. If the function does not return anything, that type must be `void`.

Comment: If there's a `using`-directive is it better to have the prototypes go before or after it?

Answer (score 12):

You cannot use a *name/symbol* which is **not** yet *declared*. That is the whole reason.

It is like this:

```
i = 10;  //i not yet declared

int i;
```

That is **wrong** too, exactly for the same reason. The compiler doesn't know what `i` *is* – it doesn't really care what it *will* be.

Just like you write this (which also makes sense to you as well as the compiler):

```
int i;  //declaration (and definition too!)

i = 10;  //use
```

you've to write this:

```
void myFunction(); //declaration!

int main()
{
   myFunction() //use
}

void myFunction(){}  //definition
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can one call main() from a function on the upper side of main()?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: In C++, calling `main()` from *your* code is **forbidden**. A good compiler should give you error (or at least warning). `main()` is called by the runtime.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Just wondered that main could be seen from anywhere I know its nonsense but I wondered. :)

Answer (score 2):

most of the computer programming languages have top to down approach which means code is compiled from the top. When we define a function after main function and use it in the main [myFunction () ], compiler thinks " what is this. I never saw this before " and it generates an error saying myFunction not declared. If you want to use in this way you should give a prototype for that function before you define main function. But some compilers accept without a prototype.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void myFunction(); //prototype
int main()
{
   myFunction(); //use 
}

myFunction(){ //definition 
.......;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
myFunction()
```

has to be declared before using it. This is c++ behaviour in general.

Answer (score 0):

Functions need to be declared before they can be used:

```
void myFunction();

int main() {
  myFunction();
}

void myFunction() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to forward declare a function so main can know that there is some.

```
void myFunction();

int main()
{
   myFunction();
}

void myFunction(){}
```

Don't forget about putting `;` after each command.

Answer (score 0):

specify the function declaration before calling function .So that compiler will know about return type and signature

Answer (score 0):

Declare then define.

```
void func();
int main()
{
    func();
}
void func()
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare the function before.

```
void myFunction();

int main()
{
    myFunction()
 }

 myFunction(){}
```